# QSettings: is it possible to always save strings wrapped in double quotes?

Tags: string, qt, double-quotes, qsettings

Here is a simple test:

```
QSettings *settings = new QSettings("test.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

QStringList values;
values << "stringwith'quote"
       << "\"stringwithdoublequotes\""
       << "string"
       << "string with spaces"
       << "stringwith\nnewline"
       << "stringwith,comma"
       << "stringwith;semicolon"
       << ";"
       << ","
       << "'"
       << "',";

for (int i=0; i<values.count(); i++){
    settings->setValue("value" + QString::number(i), values[i]);
}
```

This is what the .ini looks like:

```
[General]
value0=stringwith'quote
value1=\"stringwithdoublequotes\"
value2=string
value3=string with spaces
value4=stringwith\nnewline
value5="stringwith,comma"
value6="stringwith;semicolon"
value7=";"
value8=","
value9='
value10="',"
```

Is it possible to force all the strings to be saved wrapped in double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, but kinda bvy making it yourself. You can make a method that ensures your string are properly quoted

```
QString quoted(QString word)
{
    return "\"" + word.replace('\\', "\\\\").replace('"',"\\\"").replace('\t', "\\t") + "\""
}
```

That method adds quotes, and escape some special characters.
Then you can call it on any string in your list. If you're going to use it often, you could inherit from QSetting to override method setValue and make it automatic.

Beware, the method QSettings::value is also going to need some adaptation to unquote those.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, when `settings->setValue` is called, the string are saved with the escape character: `value2=\"string\"`.